# How to generalize a point feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, generalization

I have a point featureclass with a point for every 25cm - in Total 400,000 Points.
I would like to reduce this resolution to one point every Meter. How could I instruct ArcGIS Advanced(ArcInfo) to do this? I can´t see a thinning tool or generalization tool for Point feature classes and don´t want to create a raster from the data yet to resample.

Comment: are these points forming a regular grid ? in which form the points are placed ?

Comment: What data is assigned to each point, and are you trying to retain it or sum/count/average it?

Comment: Yes...a regular grid 25cm between each point. Each point contains contamination levels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Delete Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool in ArcGIS.  You can see from the screenshots, I generated a uniform grid of points within the polygon extent and used the Delete Identical tool with a 10m XY tolerance to *thin* the points.

Alternatively, use the [Integrate (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000) tool to make points *coincident* at a certain XY tolerance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

1) create a new grid with 1 m spacing (fishnet)

2) use "spatial join" to aggregate the attributes of the points falling inside the polygons

3) create the centroids of the polygons

3b) Alternatively, you can make a spatial join between the centroids and your original points so that you can define more advanced merging rules (aka based on the distance)

Comment: Understood....so there is no Thinning tool available.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the thinning tool that is available for LAS datasets, [lasthin](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasthin/), from [LASTools](http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/) (free download).

Although I haven't used it a lot on shapefiles myself (I have tried it on LAS files though), the help text states:

> Uses lasthin.exe to thin LiDAR points by placing a uniform grid over
>   the points and keeping within each grid cell only the point with the
>   lowest (or the highest or a random) Z coordinate.
>
> The LiDAR input can be LAS, LAZ, BIN, **SHP**, ASC, or TXT. The LiDAR
>   output can be in LAS, LAZ, BIN, or TXT format.

Additinally, if you have access to FME, there's a [PointCloudThinner transformer](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Thinning-Point-Clouds-Reduce-Data-Volume) there which should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

"Thinning" implies dimensionality, which points do not possess. Given a regular grid of point values, I'd convert the points to a raster, then resample to the desired interval, and convert back to points. This would be a lot less computationally intensive than trying to solve this with vector datatypes.